# efficient algorithm for guessing

Tags: algorithm, performance, computer-science, data-mining, heuristics

I am abstracting a real world problem into the following question:

- X is a pool of all possible permutation of letters.
- Y is a pool of strings.
- F is a function that takes a candidate x from X and returns a boolean value depending on whether x belongs to Y.

F is expensive and X is huge.
What is the most efficient way to extract as many results from Y as possible?  False positives are ok.

Comment: You may want to ask your question here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have abstracted it too far.  There is no way to do better than brute force search without knowing something about F.

Comment: judging from what you told me, I can't see anything better than sequential processing. but if some results would be more "interesting" than others, and you want a better chance of seeing those interesting results earlier rather than later, randomizing the order may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce another function G which is cheap and also tests whether x belongs to y. G must return true whenever F returns true, and may return true when F returns false. First test with G, testing with F only if G returns true.

I don't see how to say anything more specific, considering the generality of your formulation.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no way to answer this question well, as most solutions to these types of problems are highly domain-specific.

You probably should try your question here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

But, to give you an example of the range of possibilities you're talking about; the Traveling Salesman problem seems similar - and is often solved with a "self organizing map": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IA6eGYMyr1A

Of course, the "solutions" people come up with to the traveling salesman problem don't have to be the BEST solution, just a GOOD solution... so your question doesn't indicate whether or not this is applicable to your situation or not.

It sounds like you're asking for some sort of more efficient brute-forcing technique... but there just isn't any.

As another example, for cracking passwords (which seems similar to your question), people often try "commonly used words / passwords" first, before resorting to total brute force... but this is, again, a domain-specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make F less expensive by implementing [Delta based score calculation](http://www.slideshare.net/ge0ffrey/drools-planner-webinar-20110615-drools-planner-optimizes-automated-planning/30). Then use metaheuristics (or branch and bound) to find as many Y's as possible (for example use [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner)).